# Reading CSV's with Pandas and dealing with comments

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This is a example of the data files I am trying to read in using *Pandas*. All the files have different number of comment lines but all start the data section with the `BEGIN` and end with `END` and maybe a newline after that.

```
!Example data file
!With commands delimited by exclamation points
!Not always the some number of comment lines
BEGIN
300,-1.0342501,-0.07359
5298,-0.9889674,0.06514
1029,-0.981307,0.130398
1529,-0.971765,0.1945281
END
```

This is my Pandas for reading in these files.

```
b = pd.read_csv(data_file,,names=['Frequency','Real','Imaginary'],comment='!')
```

There are 2 problems I am having, first is it reads all the lines and just fills the comment lines will just be *None* or *NaN* and reads the `BEGIN` and `END` tags. This also results offset in the index of the cells, this is my second problem.

What would be the correct Pandas to read this into a data frame with removing the comment lines and the `BEGIN` and `END` tags? Is there a elegant one line of code that can solve both of my problems?

Answer (score 2):

How about importing the whole file and dropping everything where the second field is blank?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
b = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv',names=['Frequency','Real','Imaginary'],comment='!')
isnotnan = lambda x: not(np.isnan(x))
b2 = b[b['Real'].apply(isnotnan)]
```

Results b:

```
  Frequency      Real  Imaginary
0       NaN       NaN        NaN
1       NaN       NaN        NaN
2       NaN       NaN        NaN
3     BEGIN       NaN        NaN
4       300 -1.034250  -0.073590
5      5298 -0.988967   0.065140
6      1029 -0.981307   0.130398
7      1529 -0.971765   0.194528
8       END       NaN        NaN
```

Results b2:

```
  Frequency      Real  Imaginary
4       300 -1.034250  -0.073590
5      5298 -0.988967   0.065140
6      1029 -0.981307   0.130398
7      1529 -0.971765   0.194528
```

To reset the index:

b3 = b2.reset_index(drop = True)

Output of b3:

```
  Frequency      Real  Imaginary
0       300 -1.034250  -0.073590
1      5298 -0.988967   0.065140
2      1029 -0.981307   0.130398
3      1529 -0.971765   0.194528
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! But what If I want the indexes to count from 0 not 4 in this case?

Comment: Check out my new version of the answer which will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of your code:

```
In [125]: df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', comment='!', header=0, names=['Frequency','Real','Imaginary'], na_values=['END'])

In [126]: df
Out[126]: 
   Frequency      Real  Imaginary
0        300 -1.034250  -0.073590
1       5298 -0.988967   0.065140
2       1029 -0.981307   0.130398
3       1529 -0.971765   0.194528
4        NaN       NaN        NaN
```

The 'END' in the last line is converted to NaN, so we'll remove the last row:

```
In [127]: df = df.iloc[:-1]    # or `df = df.dropna()`

In [128]: df
Out[128]: 
   Frequency      Real  Imaginary
0        300 -1.034250  -0.073590
1       5298 -0.988967   0.065140
2       1029 -0.981307   0.130398
3       1529 -0.971765   0.194528
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me on the sample data. It gives error "CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 3"

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  I have 0.14.1.

Comment: I have version 14.0 of Pandas.